# Mongodb query to find element value type of nested array or object in a field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, types

I have mongodb data model where I have some array fields that contain embedded objects or arrays.  I have some inconsistencies in the field in question because I've tweaked my application logic.  Initially, my model looked like this:

Initial Setup of Results collection

```
"competition" : "competition1",
"stats" : [ 
    {
        "stat1" : [],
        "stat2" : []
    }
]
```

However, I saw that this wasn't the best setup for my needs.  So I changed it to the following:

New Setup of Results collection

```
"competition" : "competition1",
"stats" : [ 
    {
        "stat1" : 3,
        "stat2" : 2
    }
 ]
```

My problem now is that documents that have the initial setup cause an error.  So what I want is to find all documents that have the initial setup and convert them to have the new setup.

How can I accomplish this in mongodb?

Here is what I've tried, but I'm stuck...

```
db.getCollection('results').find({"stats.0": { "$exists": true }})
```

But what I want is to be able to do something like

```
db.getCollection('results').find({"stats.0".stat1: { "$type": Array}})
```

Basically I want to get documents where the value of stats[0].stat1 is of type array and override the entire stats field to be an empty array.

This would fix the errors I'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/type/#querying-by-array-type) operator for arrays in older versions works little differently than what you might think than [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#querying-by-array-type) in 3.6.

This will work in 3.6

```
db.getCollection('results').find( { "stats.0.stat1" : { $type: "array" } } )
```

You can do it couple of ways for lower versions and It depends what you are looking for.

For empty arrays you can just check

```
{"stats.0.stat1":{$size:0}}
```

For non empty arrays

```
{"stats.0.stat1": {$elemMatch:{ "$exists": true }}}
```

Combine both using `$or` for finding both empty and non empty array.

For your use case you can use below update

```
db.getCollection('results').update({"stats.0.stat1":{$size:0}}, {$set:{"stats":[]}})
```